# Is it possible for me to create a view that displays all records from a table within a month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing queries and views for a database. I want to create a view that the user can easily use to view records weekly or monthly. I know i can use DATEDIFF() but I just want a view that will display information within a particular month or week. so I won't need to edit anything. Any ideas or is it possible?

Comment: yes.. it is possible.. you should search and read further to accomplish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Current Day Records:

```
SELECT date,subject,description FROM table_name
WHERE DATE( date ) = CURDATE( );
```

For Current Month Records:

```
SELECT date,subject,description FROM table_name
WHERE MONTH( date ) = MONTH(NOW());
```

For Current year Records:

```
SELECT date,subject,description FROM table_name
WHERE YEAR( date ) = YEAR(NOW());
```

For selected date records,first you need to add datepicker in input type and do the following:
Here 'datepicker' is the html form input type name.

```
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];

$sql ="SELECT date,subject,description FROM table_name WHERE date='$date'";
```

For selected month records:
Here 'month' is the html form input type name.

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['month']);

$sql ="SELECT date,subject,description FROM table_name WHERE MONTH(date)='". mysql_real_escape_string($date)  ."'";
```

For selected year records:
Here 'year' is the html form input type name.

```
$date = $_POST['year'];

$sql ="SELECT date,subject,description FROM table_name WHERE YEAR(date)='$date'";
```

Comment: Same here: `WHERE MONTH( t_date ) = MONTH(NOW())` will also match dates one year ago in the same month.

Comment: My pleasure...hope this will be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the structure the your table.

It should have (or you can create them) a row related somehow to time. Than you can create a PHP function to pull out the data you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using date and time functions (MONTH(), YEAR(), DAY())

Last 1 day:
`SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY score DESC;`

Last 7 days:
`SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) ORDER BY score DESC;`

Last 30 days:
`SELECT * FROM jokes WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) ORDER BY score DESC;`

There are many SQL date/time functions that allow you to do this.
Go through SQL functions to know more.

You can design separate pages for Daily/Weekly/Monthly entries and show respective data on those pages.

Comment: Consider that `WEEKOFYEAR(date)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())` will also match the week one year ago and every year before.

Comment: Corrected the queries.

Comment: Thanks  Vivek. This really help. :)